# DialogFlow - Restore - Keep Training

Tags: dialogflow-es, restore

in my company, we are developing a bot with DialogFlow and find this platform quite convenient. However, we are experiencing a difficulty since every time that we have to move a version of the agent to the production environment through a restore of the development agent, we lose the training of the bot in production.
I would like to know if there is an equivalent way to move an agent to production environment without losing former training.

Thanks in advance,

Ricardo.

Comment: what do you mean by "lose the training of bot"?

Comment: If I am not wrong once the agent gets working improves its conversational skills, basically conversation, through ongoing training, basically it adds more entities and "user says" parametrization to the intents, so that more natural speech is recognized. Unfortunately if I import an intent developed within another agent, I will lose all the learning (training) developed by the production agent. Is this right? Any way to workaround this?